# Control/information on call windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm new to windows phone 8, and I was wondering if there is a way to have control over the calling function. For example, I'd like to be able to stop a call when it is a certain number, and be able to save a list of "spam" numbers in a list. Code isn't necessary, I was just wondering what namespaces to start from.

Comment: You cannot intercept phone calls or stop them in windows phone.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in the windows phone.